# Lambda sorting of one vector using another vector in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, stdvector

I am trying to sort a list of int indices in a vector x2 using a corresponding double vector x_values. I am using std::sort on x2 using a comparator that looks at x_values. However, the output is not what I was expecting and I can't figure out why.

Here is some example code to show what I'm talking about:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int numParticles = 2;
    std::vector<double> x_values(4);

    std::vector<int> x2(4);

    std::iota(x2.begin(), x2.begin() + numParticles, 0);
    std::iota(x2.begin() + numParticles, x2.end(), 0);

    x_values = { -0.3,-0.2,-0.1,1.0 };

    std::cout << "\nx values presort: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        std::cout << x_values[i] << " " << x2[i] << "\n";
    }

    std::sort(x2.begin(), x2.end(), [&x_values](int i1, int i2) {return x_values[i1] < x_values[i2]; });

    std::cout << "\nx index post sort: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        std::cout << x2[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

The first output gives a result of:

```
x values presort: 
-0.3 0
-0.2 1
-0.1 0
1 1
```

While the second gives an output of:

```
x index post sort: 
0
0
1
1
```

I was expecting the second to give an output of:

```
x index post sort: 
0
1
0
1
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *I was expecting the second to give an output of: 0 1 0 1* Why? After you sorted `x2` it's now in an ascending order.

Comment: If I was just sorting x2 without the lambda function, I would agree. The result I'm seeing could be the result of the lambda function not being called, but it could be the lambda working not as I intended. 

I want x2 to be sorted into the ascending order of the x_values - not the ascending order of x2.

Comment: It is sorted in ascending order of x_values - `x_values[0], x_values[0], x_values[1], x_values[1]` what else do you expect? We cannot say what you are doing wrong without you explaining why you expect `0,1,0,1`

Comment: I was expecting the comparison to be done using the value contained by the x_values vector, not their indices. I was expecting 0,1,0,1 because the doubles inside of x_values are {-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,1.0}. The corresponding values in x2 are {0,1,0,1}. Does that make sense?

Comment: @TimothyArtz In your lambda, `i1` and `i2` are always either `0` or `1`

Comment: Thanks @DeanSeo. Do you see an easy way to make i1 and i2 equal to `0 1 2 3` for comparing, but still sort the `0` and `1` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value `0` in `x2` is sorted as if it were `x_values[0]` aka `-0.3`.
A value `1` in `x2` is sorted as if it were `x_values[1]` aka `-0.2`.

So the sorted vector is `0 0 1 1` corresponding to `-0.3 -0.3 -0.2 -0.2`

I do not understand your confusion, why you expected something else.

---

Let me rephrase what your comparer does:

`i1` from `x2` comes before `i2` from `x2` if `x_values[i1] < x_values[i2]`

Comment: I understand now. I'm quite new to C++. I was not understanding how the lambda function worked. I thought that the four values that would be place into `i1` and `i2` would be `0 1 2 3` corresponding to `-0.3 -0.2 -0.1 1.0`. What you have shown me is that the values placed into `i1` and `i2` are `x2[0] x2[1] x2[2] x2[3]` which of course is `0 1 0 1`. 

What I need to do to get the result I want is to make another vector, say `x3` and give it the values `0 1 2 3`. I can then run the sort, which will give me back `0 1 2 3`. I can then use that result to rearrange `x2` to get `0 1 0 1`
Thanks!

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve, but when you use 3 vectors for 1 sort you are overcomplicating things

Comment: I have a set of real values that correspond to the start and end coordinates of some objects in a 1D space. I need to get the order of the object indices sorted by the value of the coordinates. In this example, object 0 goes from [-0.3,-0.1] and object 1 goes from [-0.2,1.0]. By sorting the start and end points, I can observe that the two objects overlap on [-0.2,-0.1]. It's part of an algorithm that does Sweep and Prune Broad Phase Collision Detection, more info on that here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_and_prune.

If you have any thoughts on using fewer vectors, I'd be interested.

Comment: @TimothyArtz I would do it with 1 vector of `struct X { double coord; int obj; };`